# WPF browser application: how to put link like html anchor

Tags: wpf

How 2 put a link/navigation in my WPF browser applications XAML file ?  Like a user menu or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx) maybe? Just put it inside `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock>
 <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">Google</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```